# How to move rect in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I try to have a rect which moves with the mouse pointer. However, I seem to have a problem with calling the paint method. It either doesn't draw or creates artifacts. The only clean picture I get is with a forced redraw (zoom the graph).

Here's my mwe

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg


class RectItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        self.generate_picture()

    def generate_picture(self):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        painter.setPen(pg.mkPen('r'))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect)
        painter.end()

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        print('paint')
        painter.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())

    def move(self, x, y):
        print(f'{x} {y}')
        self.rect.moveCenter(QtCore.QPointF(x, y))
        self.generate_picture()


class PlotWidget(pg.PlotWidget):
    mouse_moved = QtCore.pyqtSignal(float, float)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.sig = pg.SignalProxy(
            self.scene().sigMouseMoved,
            rateLimit=60,
            slot=self._mouse_moved,
        )

    def _mouse_moved(self, event):
        pos, = event

        mousePoint = self.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
        x = mousePoint.x()
        y = mousePoint.y()

        self.mouse_moved.emit(x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = PlotWidget()
    rect = RectItem()
    main.mouse_moved.connect(rect.move)
    main.addItem(rect)

    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just redrawing the contents of an internal QPicture doesn't affect the graphics item in any way, you must call `update()` in order to correctly refresh the item. Also consider that since you're actually changing the bounding rect of the item, you must also call [`prepareGeometryChange()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#prepareGeometryChange) *before* changing the geometry, otherwise you'll see artifacts due to the previous rectangle position not correctly cleared up.

```
    def move(self, x, y):
        self.rect.moveCenter(QtCore.QPointF(x, y))
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        self.generate_picture()
        self.update()
```

Also, if you only need a rectangle to move around with the mouse, consider using the simpler [QGraphicsRectItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsrectitem.html) which doesn't require any painting implementation.